# Is simultaneous pole-to-pole stacked orbit of planets around a star possible?

Tags: orbital-motion

I read recently that mercury, mars and earth once had concentric simultaneous orbits pole-to-pole under each other; all of which orbited under Saturns south pole around the sun. In sort of a stacked configuration. Is this possible? *see url below, page 8 illustration*

http://saturniancosmology.org/pdf/Saturnian%20Cosmology%20-%20Chapter%2013%20-%20The%20Creation.pdf

Comment: From the link: `"Saturn went nova and started to blaze like a sun in about 4100 BC (probably 4077 BC)"`. In case people are wondering whether to click through.

Answer (score 3):

No, this sort of configuration is emphatically **not** possible. In real gravity (you know, the one in the real world) planets orbit the Sun in ellipses which have the Sun in one of the [foci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Focus), which is *in the plane of the ellipse*. This is patently not the case in the configuration in that link,

[image]

which means that the link is wrong. Period.